# Real scalar field with a set of interacting particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

This is quite complicated. I will appreciate if you give some hint of this problem.

First we have the following Lagrangian, $L= L_f+L_i$, where $L_f$ is just the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian
\begin{align}
L_f = \frac{1}{2} \int d^3x [(\frac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial t})^2 - c^2 (\nabla\phi(x,t))^2-\mu^2 \phi^2(x,t)]
\end{align}
and $L_i(t)$ gives interaction between field and a set of particles,
\begin{align}
L_i = -\sum_n g_n \phi(x_n(t),t) + \sum_n \frac{m_n}{2}(\dot x_n(t))^2 - V(x_n(t)).
\end{align}

In this case, the question requires three things.

(1) The field equation for $\phi$.

(2) $\phi$ in terms of creation/annihilation operators in interaction picture.

(3) Total Hamiltonian.

I do not know how I can approach to this problem. Is this okay to change  $\phi(x_n(t),t)$ as $\int d^3 x \phi(x,t)\delta(x-x_n(t))$ to find the field equation? In this regard, the field equation is
\begin{align}
-\mu^2 \phi(x,t) - \sum_n g_n\delta(x-x_n(t)) = \ddot\phi - c^2\nabla^2\phi .
\end{align}

However, I am fully doubtful about this approach. Furthermore I don't know how to proceed into (2) and (3). Could you just give me some hint of this problem?

Comment: Identify canonical momentum corresponding to KG field using $\pi(\vec{x})=\frac{\delta}{\delta \dot{\phi(\vec{x})}}L$ and point particles using $p_{n}^{}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}}L$. Find Hamiltonian by Legendre transformation. Quantize the theory by imposing equal time canonical commutation relations. Write Quantum evolution equation for $\phi(\vec{x},t)$ and $x(t)$. Fourier express temporal variation of $\phi(\vec{x},t)$, identify positive frequency component as creation part and negative component as annihilation part. I am not sure if you will have to worry about any subtelities.